# mvc rewrite rule for GET form

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have this rule:
`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

When i send GET form it is not work. For example `http://192.168.1.100/site/admin/analytics/chart?view=daily` should be `http://192.168.1.100/site/admin/analytics/chart/view/daily`

What should be the second rule?

Comment: Have you ensured that `RewriteEngine On` is there too?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about here is something different.  You only have part of the code you need.

You are correct with the rule you already have -

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This rule will "capture" **any incoming request** and pass everything after the domain name  to `index.php` as a `$_GET` parameter - `?url=$1`.  The `$1` is what you captured in the regular expression `^(.+)$` - Everything between the brackets is captured.  So you are alright so far...

The next piece of the puzzle is what you do inside `index.php` which received the original URL as a GET parameter.  You have to parse *that* parameter in order to know what page to return to the user.

Lets take something like this for example -

`http://yourdomain.com/user/123`

What you'd do inside `index.php` would be something like this -

```
$originalURL = $_GET['url'];
$URLParts = explode('/',$originalURL);
```

Now you have inside of `$URLParts`

```
Array (
 'user',
 '123'
)
```

From here its your decision how exactly you output your data to the user - but I'll give a rough example for clarity -

```
// Get base module - array_pop() also removes it from the array 
$baseModule = array_pop($URLParts); 
$requestData = $URLParts; // Collect all other data that was passed
switch($baseModule){
  case "user":
    // If we know the request is for a user page, we know the next URL part
    // will be the user id.  Use it to fetch user information from our database.
    $userID = $requestData[0]
    $user = getUserByID($userID);
    echo $user['name'] . "<br/>";
    echo "<img src='". $user['picture'] ."' width='300' >";
    break;
  case "picture":
    echo "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/s5cH9.png' width='300' >";
    break;
  case "video":
    echo "<a href='http://youtu.be/Xk_XaJ7gE4Q' target='_blank' >Video Link</a>";
    break;
  default:
    echo "404 - The page you requested was not found.";
    break;
}
exit();
```

With this code in place, your system will know exactly what to do when a request comes in for -

- `http://yourdomain.com/user/123`
- `http://yourdomain.com/picture`
- `http://yourdomain.com/video`

even if you give it some junk URL, it'll give you a conservative message that the page you requested was not found.

---

One thing to note here is that you should always be careful when using incoming data.  A request could be coming in from some malicious script trying to find security holes in your system.  You should treat all incoming data (for example anything in `$_GET`) as a potential threat.  You need to be sure that you know what data you have in your hands.

A practical example of this would be using a user_id that was sent to us in an SQL query.  We know we are finding a  user by their ID, so the data we have **must be numerical**.  You could validate that by calling [`.intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) - this will ensure that you have a numerical value in your SQL.  There are many more (probably better) techniques to prevent these things but that is a different topic and this was just a note at the end of an already long post. :)